# Converting Backbone's Todo List example from localStorage

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, mongoose, express

I have been looking at the [Todo list example](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/examples/todos/index.html) ([source](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/todos.html)) for [Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/).  The code uses local storage, and I wanted to try and convert it so that it operated via a RESTful webservice.

Suppose the webservice already exists at the route `todos/`.  I figured I need to add in a `url` piece into `Backbone.Model.extend` and remove the `localStorage: new Store("todos")` line when we perform `Backbone.collection.extend`.

```
  window.Todo = Backbone.Model.extend({

    url : function() {
      return  'todos/'+this.id;
    }

    // Default attributes for a todo item.
    defaults: function() {
      return {
        done:  false,
        order: Todos.nextOrder()
      };
    },

    // Toggle the `done` state of this todo item.
    toggle: function() {
      this.save({done: !this.get("done")});
    }

  });
```

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Url should be set in Collection, if you have need for diferent urls than those created by collection than declare url in model.

You need to remove

```
  <script src="../backbone-localstorage.js"></script>
```

from index.html since it is linked after backbone.js and effectively overrides Backbone's sync method to store in localStorage.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried those two changes and todos.js still isn't grabbing todos from the service.  Am I setting url correctly?  Any chance you could post code for a working todos.js?  Looking at http://www.jamesyu.org/2011/01/27/cloudedit-a-backbone-js-tutorial-by-example, do I also need to extend controllers, too?

Comment: And what request is sent to backend?

Answer (score 0):

I would leave the model as it is in the Todos example. In the collection class add this property:

```
window.TodoList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    ...     
    url: '/todos',
    ...
}
```

Calling `fetch()` on the collection should retrieve a list of Todo objects.

If you are using Rails you need to set `ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = false` otherwise Backbone.js will not be able to pull out the Todo objects from the returned json.